# Create user Active Directory: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. thrown at UserPrincipal

Tags: active-directory, userprincipal

When I try to create user in active directory I get an exception:

> (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED)) error

Code:

```
UserPrincipal userPrincipal = new UserPrincipal(principalContext);
userPrincipal.SamAccountName = serviceAccount.SAMAccountName;
userPrincipal.PasswordNeverExpires = serviceAccount.PasswordNeverExpires;
userPrincipal.SetPassword(passwordOfAccount);
userPrincipal.Enabled = serviceAccount.Enabled;

// Creates the account
try
{
    userPrincipal.Save();
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    return false;
}
return true;
```

I get the error at

```
userPrincipal.Save();
```

Comment: PrincipalContext principalContext = null;
            try
            {
                //The principalContext needs to be initialized with the credentials provided for the QA environment.
                principalContext = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, domain, environment, "xyz", "D[u.Aa39BK*t@j)_");
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                return false;
            }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`E_ACCESSDENIED` means that the account you are using to do this does not have permissions to do what you're doing.

You don't show your code where you create your `PrincipalContext` object, but if you did not give it a username and password, then it is using whatever credentials the process is running under, which sounds like it's not good enough.

You need to use [one of the `PrincipalContext` constructors that lets you provide a username and password](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.principalcontext.-ctor?view=netframework-4.8#System_DirectoryServices_AccountManagement_PrincipalContext__ctor_System_DirectoryServices_AccountManagement_ContextType_System_String_System_String_System_String_). For example:

```
var principalContext = new PrincipalContext(
                            ContextType.Domain,
                            "example.com",
                            "ou=Users,dc=example,dc=com",
                            "username",
                            "password"
                       );
```

Where `"example.com"` is your domain name, `""ou=Users,dc=example,dc=com""` is the OU where you want to create the accounts, and `"username"` and `"password"` belong to an account that has permissions to create user accounts in that OU.

Comment: Hello Gabriel Luci, I am giving the username and password and it has full permission in Active Directory to create user. It is creating the user and then throwing the error. code is as follow    PrincipalContext principalContext = null;
            try
            {
                //The principalContext needs to be initialized with the credentials provided for the QA environment.
                principalContext = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, domain, environment, "xyz", "D[u.Aa39BK*t@j)_");
            }

Comment: I see. In that code, you are setting the password, so you also need "Reset password" permissions. You are also setting the `sAMAccountName` and `userAccountControl` attributes, so make sure the account has permission to modify those attributes.